# Cannot align image to the bottom of a li element

Tags: css, image, html, vertical-alignment

I've been reading other related posts but I could not find a solution to my particular problem. Here it is:
I created a slider based on jCarouselLite to display books. It works fine but I would like to position the images at the bottom regardless of the height. I mean, as it is now, shorter images align to the top of the LI. I know that the parent container must be set to position: relative and the child element to absolute. I believe the parent box is ".carousel" and the child is the image contained inside the element LI. I tried several options to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    .slider {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3em;
}
.carousel {
    float: left;
    width: 68.75%; /*72.916666667%;*/
    background: #CCCCCC;
    height: 210px!important;
    position: relative; /* DOES NOT WORK */
}
.carousel ul li{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
}
.carousel ul li img{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        position: absolute; /* DOES NOT WORK */
bottom: 0;      /* DOES NOT WORK */
}
-----HTML-----
<div class="slider">
    <div class="carousel">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_002.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="1"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_small.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="2"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_005.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_006.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_007.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_008.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_010.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="../static/images/getcover_011.jpe" title="#titulo_libro"  alt="3"></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but aligning the images to the bottom would work if you'd made the list elements relative and the image absolute (like you're doing now).

I updated your example a bit, gave the list elements a border, widht and height so you can see them ending up at the bottom.

```
ul li{
   position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/x79H4/

Comment: That's it! Adding height and width to the LI element did the trick. Thanks a lot Jaap!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to shift the absolute position to the li element and then use height 100% coupled with a min-height 100% on the inner image. I'm not sure why you are using display: table-cell on the li elements, this seems unnecessary.

```
.carousel ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel ul li img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle. The images are only 150px tall:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJdSG/